# Which tool to measure shaft alignment for small diameter shafts (d=10mm)?

Tags: motors, mechanical, coupling

I have seen many tools and methods to check shaft alignment, but they are mostly used for big shaft. I wonder if there are small tools for small diameter shaft with limited space to install?

Can you suggest some tools, brands and sources that I can find more information?

Comment: It would be useful to edit your question to include a drawing or photo of the application for which you are making your query. One can use a dial indicator for any size shaft, but it may not be suited to your situation.

Comment: This is too vague because context and application matter. What you use depends on what reference surfaces you have available and those references surfaces may be parallel, perpendicular, or even some other angle relative to your shaft. For example, on a mill, the spindle aligns to be perpendicular to the table, but on a lathe it aligns to be parallel to the table. Completely different. There is no one set way and some setups may need special tools built just to measure that particular case.